# Charcter encoding and PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, multilingual

I'm building a multilingual website that uses PHP to load language files. Paragraphs in the language file are set in define() constants. 
After opening page in the browser I get a bunch of characters like "?". In the markup I have encoding set to utf-8. What can be done to make it work other than replacing all unknown characters with html character entities?

Comment: There is one more thing to point out. Language files are included to the script with include() function. If I declare language variables right in the script then characters are showing fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you language files are utf8,
2. make sure your HTML files and template are utf8,
3. make sure you add the following tag to your page

   < meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" / >

as long as your data is utf8, the template and html files are utf8 and you explicitely specify the html page is utf8, it should work.

EDIT: the code embedding thing is a bit broken today... have to insert a space at the tag opening.weird

Comment: I don't know much about character encoding...my variables look like this: define('COMM_NAV_ABOUT','Σχετικά με εμάς'); This will output as "?????????????"

Comment: make sure your file is saved as utf8.

Comment: Thank you. My main php editor doesn't have the option to change character encoding. I opened the file in notepad++, saved it as utf-8 and Voila! Thank you all!

Comment: @marcin_koss. Nice. Glad it's sorted. For other people running in the same issue but on Macs, use Text Wrangler, Coda or TextMate, they all have the option to set the encoding.

Answer (score 3):

header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');

use this line on the top of your PHP code to send header; also helps with validation of dynamic pages to get rid of utf warning.