# How do I use Unicode for SEO?

Tags: unicode, seo, html-entities

I have been writing for a website. while writing content i came across two options:
1.) Writing `Népal` or
2.) Writing `N&eacute;pal` writing both prints Népal.

Now i have been confused which one is the correct one and why? Should i use htmlentities to encode or change `Népal` to `N&eacute;pal`

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna go against Paul and say use utf-8 for everything.

Make sure your database use utf-8 collation, make sure your html source files are saved as utf8 and make sure your Content-Type meta tag is utf8 and you're cruising..

See [this somewhat related recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236661/charcter-encoding-and-php/).

It is so much easier than dealing with html entities, google indexes it fine and browser support is totally sufficient these days.

Comment: Absolutely. Provided the encoding is declared as UTF-8, it's perfectly valid (HTML 4 and 5) and will work in all browsers and is easier to manage and work with too.

Comment: I concur with answer + comment

Answer (score -1):

You should escape the character (`&eacute;`), it will be guaranteed to work across all browsers in that case.

If you don't it can end up with some browsers with some character sets not displaying it right, or displaying gibberish. If I don't encode my french accents, sometimes I can end up with little square boxes instead of actual accented characters because of browser issues.

Also, for SEO, all search engines worth a damn will be able to understand htmlentities.

Comment: I'm gonna take a wild guess and that the "sometimes" behaviour your describe is caused by an html source file not saved as utf8 - it's the number one case for that problem, imho.